# JUnit testing conversion from one class to another

Tags: java, testing, intellij-idea, junit

*(Updated to add more details on classes)*

I'm a testing beginner, and I'm looking to test a conversion method.

The method I'm trying to test, will convert an Object of one type, and return an object of another, e.g. convert UserOne object to UserTwo object, and I then want to check a property on the UserTwo object, to make sure the conversion was correct.

*(Update)*

What I wanted to do is create a NewUser object, passing a TBUser object into the original convert method, and then test the returning object from that method, to ensure the conversion was correct.

My issue was where to create and then pass the objects.

```
class TBUserStringToNew***UserConverterTest extends groovy.util.GroovyTestCase {
void setUp() {
    super.setUp();
    TBUser tbUser = new TBUser();
    tbUser.setContactNumber1("0123456789");
}

void tearDown() {
}

@Test
void testConvert() {
    New***User nUser = testConvert(tbUser);
    Assert.assertEquals("0123456789", nUser.getContactNumber());
}
```

NewUser Class:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class NewUser implements Serializable {

@JsonProperty("ID")
private Integer id = 0;

@JsonProperty("eID")
private Integer eId;

@JsonProperty("Forename")
private String forename;

@JsonProperty("Surname")
private String surname;

@JsonProperty("DateOfBirth")
private String dateOfBirth;

@JsonProperty("AddressLineOne")
private String addressLineOne;

@JsonProperty("AddressLineTwo")
private String addressLineTwo;

@JsonProperty("PostCode")
private String postCode;

@JsonProperty("PostCodeArea")
private String postCodeArea;

@JsonProperty("ContactNumber")
private  String contactNumber;

@JsonProperty("EmailAddress")
private String emailAddress;

@JsonProperty("ReferralSource")
private String referralSource;

@JsonProperty("ReferralDetails")
private String referralDetails;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Integer getEId() {
    return eId;
}

public void setEId(Integer eId) {
    this.eId = eId;
}

public String getForename() {
    return forename;
}

public void setForename(String forename) {
    this.forename = forename;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}

public String getDateOfBirth() {
    return dateOfBirth;
}

public void setDateOfBirth(String dateOfBirth) {
    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
}

public String getAddressLineOne() {
    return addressLineOne;
}

public void setAddressLineOne(String addressLineOne) {
    this.addressLineOne = addressLineOne;
}

public String getAddressLineTwo() {
    return addressLineTwo;
}

public void setAddressLineTwo(String addressLineTwo) {
    this.addressLineTwo = addressLineTwo;
}

public String getPostCode() {
    return postCode;
}

public void setPostCode(String postCode) {
    this.postCode = postCode;
}

public String getPostCodeArea() {
    return postCodeArea;
}

public void setPostCodeArea(String postCodeArea) {
    this.postCodeArea = postCodeArea;
}

public String getContactNumber() {
    return contactNumber;
}

public void setContactNumber(String contactNumber) {
    this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
}

public String getEmailAddress() {
    return emailAddress;
}

public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
    this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
}

public String getReferralSource() {
    return referralSource;
}

public void setReferralSource(String referralSource) {
    this.referralSource = referralSource;
}

public String getReferralDetails() {
    return referralDetails;
}

public void setReferralDetails(String referralDetails) {
    this.referralDetails = referralDetails;
}
```

TBUserStringToNewUserConverter Class:

```
public class TBUserStringToNewUserConverter implements Converter<String, NewUser> {

protected static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());
private SimpleDateFormat nSdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@Autowired
private PlacesService placesService;

private NewUser convert(@NonNull TBUser tbUserIn) {

    ValidationErrors validationErrors = new ValidationErrors();

    String dob = null;

    try {
        dob = dayFormat.format(nlcSdf.parse(
                tbUserIn.getDob()
                .replace("T", " ")
                .replace("Z", "")));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        ValidationError validationError = new ValidationError();
        validationError.setMessage(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        validationErrors.add(validationError);
    }

    NewUser nUser = new NewUser();
    nUser.setEId(tbUserIn.getId());
    nUser.setId(tbUserIn.getExternalId());
    nUser.setForename(tbUserIn.getFirstName());
    nUser.setSurname(tbUserIn.getSurname());
    nUser.setDateOfBirth(dob);
    nUser.setEmailAddress(tbUserIn.getEmail());
    nUser.setContactNumber(tbUserIn.getContactNumber1());

    TBAddress userAddress = tbUserIn.getAddress();

    String[] splitPostCode = userAddress.getPostzip().split("\\s+");
    nUser.setPostCodeArea(splitPostCode[0]);
    nUser.setPostCode(splitPostCode[1]);

    //standard source for all users
    nUser.setReferralSource("Healthy Living Centre");

    //placeholder referral details
    nUser.setReferralDetails("Referral Reasons: Weight Reduction, Mental Health, Respiratory, Other (Some other reason I entered). " +
            "\\r\\nMedical Conditions: Medical Conditions " +
            "\\r\\nMedications: Medications " +
            "\\r\\nReferral Source: Bob O Donnell\\r\\n(Doctor Medical) " +
            "\\r\\nRisks: May attempt something " +
            "\\r\\nOther Info: Other Relevant Info:");

    return nUser;
}
```

**Test Class**

```
class TBUserStringToNewUserConverterTest extends groovy.util.GroovyTestCase {
void setUp() {
    super.setUp();
    TBUser tbUser = new TBUser();

}

void tearDown() {
}

@Test
void testConvert() {
    tbUser.setContactNumber1("");
    NewUser nUser = testConvert(tbUser);
    Assert.assertEquals("0123456789", nUser.getContactNumber());
}
```

Comment: What are the "***" chars about in your source code?

Comment: Has some business specific names, and blanking them out, could have deleted or changed them just as easily I suppose

Comment: Please: read that link [mcve] again. You should not post ALL your code, just something that is complete enough to show your problem. Then: your code still is illogical! You are defining `TBUser tbUser = new TBUser();` **within** the setUp() method. How could your test method then **use** that variable? tbUser is a local variable in one method, so how do you expect another method use that? Seriously: if you don't understand the differences between a local variable and a field, then using such frameworks and writing such code is totally overburdening you right now.

Comment: I appreciate your time, I probably didn't explain myself properly, or even understand my issue fully, I got a little help locally though, and worked out my problem

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a first glance, I think you just go step by step, like:

Your `setUp()` only does set up the most basic thing, that `tbUser` object:

```
void setUp() {
    super.setUp();
    TBUser tbUser = new TBUser();
}
```

Then, you have **one** test per attribute that requires conversion.

```
@Test
void testConvert() {
    tbUser.setContactNumber1("0123456789");
    NewUser nUser = testConvert(tbUser);
    Assert.assertEquals("0123456789", nUser.getContactNumber());
}
```

As simple as that: one test method *per* attribute that needs to be converted.

Of course, for that to work, that tbUser must be a **field** of your test class:

```
class TBUserStringToNewUserConverterTest extends groovy.util.GroovyTestCase {

  private TbUser;

  void setUp() {
    tbUser = new TbUser();
```

...

But please note: this still looks strange. At least when using JUnit, you would need the @Before annotation on any method that is supposed to be executed each time before each test. I am not familiar enough with that Groovy base class. So I am just hoping that the above does the right thing.

Comment: I can't access the tbUser object, and it's getter/setter methods, when it's set it up like that. It's giving me a "Cannot resolve symbol" warning on the tbUser object

Comment: Then put up a full [mcve] ... that sounds really dubious.

Comment: Added a bit more code, hope it gives a bit more information

Answer (score 0):

Just posting for completeness: After a bit more help, I needed to make the convert(TBUser) method public, to access from the Test class, and needed to create an instance of the converter class, and use that to access the convert method, and pass in the TBUser, and receive the converted NewUser back:

```
public class TBUserStringToNewUserConverterTest {

TBUser tbUser;
TBAddress tbAddress;
TBUserStringToNewUserConverter converter;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    converter = new TBUserStringToNewUserConverter();

    tbUser = new TBUser();
    tbUser.setId(42);
    tbUser.setFirstName("Brian");
    tbUser.setSurname("Blessed");
    tbUser.setDob("2018-10-22 15:43:35");
    tbUser.setEmail("blessed@testmail.com");
    tbUser.setContactNumber1("0123456789");

    tbAddress = new TBAddress();
    tbAddress.setAddressLine1("41 John street");
    tbAddress.setAddressLine2("Flat Road");
    tbAddress.setId("Jst");
    tbAddress.setPostzip("G47 0JJ");
    tbAddress.setTown("Derry");
    tbAddress.setCountryCCA3("IRE");

    tbUser.setAddress(tbAddress);
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
}

@Test
public void testConvert(){
    NewUser n = converter.convert(tbUser);
    Assert.assertNotNull(n);
    Assert.assertEquals("HLC", n.getReferralSource());
    Assert.assertEquals("0JJ", n.getPostCode());
    Assert.assertEquals("BT47", n.getPostCodeArea());
}
```